# Get Quote Item from Product Id

Tags: magento2, quoteitem, checkoutsession

I am trying to get the Lastly added Quote Item using "checkout/session".

By I don't know, how to get the last added Item. Hence I have product_id.

I believe instead of loading the collection and all, there would be some function. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Not lastly added product, but lastly added quote item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this. you can use getItemByProduct() method to get quote item from quote using product.

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
$item = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product); // pass the product object

$itemId = $item->getId();
```

Comment: I expect something else this. Unfortunately, in my case, it doesn't help. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last quoteId from checkout session...then load quote model to get quote item match with `product_id` what you want from quote id

```
protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
){
     $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}
public function execute(){
     $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastQuoteId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/** **Do not use checkoutSession->getQuote()**!!! it will cause infinite loop for `quotes with trigger_recollect = 1`, see `Quote::_afterLoad()` */

```
    $items = $request->getAllItems();
    if (empty($items)) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $firstItem */
    $firstItem = reset($items);
    if (!$firstItem) {
        return false;
    }

    $quote = $firstItem->getQuote();
    if (!($quote instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote)) {
        return false;
    }
```